# How can I trash multiple posts at once from the front end?

Tags: front-end, nonce, trash

I took a peek at the code in edit.php and am now generating links with this code:

```
wp_nonce_url("/wp-admin/edit.php?doaction=trash&amp;post_type=post&amp;ids=postIds", "bulk-posts")
```

The string "postIds" in the URL gets replaced by comma-separated post IDs via javascript. All this does thus far is redirect me to the edit screen in the backend. How do I need to generate this link to trash multiple posts at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be `action` instead of "doaction", then it will work just fine.

As for your request for some documentation, as far as I know there is no overview about parameters/actions available at `edit.php`. So lets do some source code inspection, as you said yourself, you have gotten the inpiration for your approach from the `edit.php`, so we start there.
You have gotten mixed up because of the variable [`$doaction`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.2-branch/wp-admin/edit.php#L56), which does get set up like this:

```
$doaction = $wp_list_table->current_action();
```

Now we need to know how `$wp_list_table` is [initialized](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.2-branch/wp-admin/edit.php#L32):

```
$wp_list_table = _get_list_table('WP_Posts_List_Table');
```

So by using [`_get_list_table()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/list-table.php#L22), which does

> Fetch an instance of a WP_List_Table class.

In this case, as seen from the call, [`WP_Posts_List_Table`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L10).

As seen above the method [`current_action()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L354) gets called to determine the action. This does actually rely on the parent class

```
return parent::current_action();
```

which is the class [`WP_List_Table`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L11), where the action gets set up by [`current_action()`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php#L462) like this:

```
/**
 * Get the current action selected from the bulk actions dropdown.
 *
 * @since 3.1.0
 * @access public
 *
 * @return string|false The action name or False if no action was selected
 */
public function current_action() {
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['filter_action'] ) && ! empty( $_REQUEST['filter_action'] ) )
        return false;
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && -1 != $_REQUEST['action'] )
        return $_REQUEST['action'];
    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['action2'] ) && -1 != $_REQUEST['action2'] )
        return $_REQUEST['action2'];
    return false;
}
```

Recognized - at the `edit.php` that is - values for the parameter `action` are:

- `trash`
- `untrash`
- `edit`
- `delete` and `delete_all`

as it can be seen at the [`switch` statement for `$doaction`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.2-branch/wp-admin/edit.php#L87) and beforehand the [extra condition for `delete_all`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4.2-branch/wp-admin/edit.php#L66).

Comment: Don't mention it, you're welcome. Ah, ok, I see it now :) I'm cleaning up the comments, you can do the same, if you want to @Florian